# check ldap access rights with python

Tags: python, ldap, acl

I am writing a web frontend (django) for an LDAP server. There are different kinds of people with different kinds of privileges, so I set up LDAP ACL to control who gets to see or edit a specific attribute.
Now its easy to determine if a specific user has read access - try to read, and you will see what you get.
But I don't see an elegant way to distinguish between read and write access *before* I actually try to write some changes. That is, I would like to make it clear in the interface, if the logged in user has write access, or can only read. So that users won't try to edit an attribute which they can not.

The only thing that came to my mind was to try to temporarily write some sort of dummy into an attribute, and see if that was successful. If so, the original value would be restored, and I know that this user has write access. I can then display this attribute as editable.
The problem with this is that if the server crashes after the dummy has been written and before the original value has been restored, I am left with dummy values in my LDAP server.

What I would need is some way to query the ACLs, in a way similar that I can query schema definitions. But maybe that is "forbidden" by LDAP?

Any ideas?

Isaac

Comment: Which Ldap server do you use? Which interface/bindings do you use to access it?

Comment: I use openldap 2.3.32 and python 2.6 ldap bindings (import ldap)

Comment: It occurs to me that I don't need to write a dummy to see if I have write access. I could just try to write the original value, which will result in an error if I don't have write access, and won't change anything if I have read access. Still, seems not so elegant.

Comment: "import ldap" produces an error in my vanilla python2.6, so you must have installed a third-party module. Which is it?

Comment: Hm, I use python-ldap from http://www.python-ldap.org/, and python 2.6.5 to be precise, both packaged for ubuntu server 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

ACL, on openldap are organized by OU and/or DN check with regexp

ex :

```
access to attrs=userPassword
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by dn.base="ou=users_with_userPassword_write_access,dc=myproduct,dc=org" write
    by dn.exact="cn=manager,dc=myproduct,dc=org" write
    by * none

access to *
    by dn.exact="cn=manager,dc=myproduct,dc=org" write
    by dn.base="ou=users_with_powerfull_write_access,dc=myproduct,dc=org" write
    by * none
```

So, regarding, the dn of the logged user (`whoami_s` with python-ldap), you can determine if user has some rights. You don't need to test if you can write the data, implement a function in your django application that check the DN.

Maybe are you saying that ACL are dinamically generated?

---

Regarding your comment, if your ACL are static, to know ACLs, the simpler way is to implement a python facility who's implement these ACLs. With my previous exemple :

```
W_ACCESS_OU = "ou=users_with_powerfull_write_access,dc=myproduct,dc=org"
def check_write_access(user_dn):
    return is_dn_base(W_ACCESS_OU, user_dn)
```

For now, python-ldap can't retrieve the slapd.conf's ACLs... And it is not safe to parse the slapd.conf (because slapd.conf can be "anywhere" on the system and ACLs declaration might be tricky to parse), also it consumes lots of time to try to write data on the LDAP backend.

I know this is not very satisfactory. Another solution is to use a "service user". Only this user has write access on the LDAP backend.

It simplifies ACL's writing :

```
access to *
    by dn.exact="cn=manager,dc=myproduct,dc=org" write
    by * none
```

Then, on regular users, you set an authorisation's flag.
Your application checks the flag when your logged user want to do something. And if this flag is OK, the service user writes data on the Backend.

This is the strategy we deploy on one of our application.

In the both case, ACL's check is done by our application, not by the ldap backend.

Comment: Sorry, I might be slow in understanding, but: if I know my DN, how do I know about the ACL? The ACL is defined in slapd.conf, which is - at least conceptually - unknown to my django app. Are you suggesting that I parse slapd.conf from django?

Comment: To answer your question: My ACL are static. Still I might change some settings once in a while, so I would like to have a single place to define them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will try the "test" approch, if its too slow maybe with some caching.
The reason why I want to keep the ACL definition only on the ldap server is that there are other ways to interact with the server (there will be cli tools, and also the standard ldap tools), so I'd like to keepall those interfaces in sync ACL wise, with just one place to define ACLs

Answer (score 0):

In OpenLDAP the ACL definitions is outside of DIT. 
If you want to access to ACL with ldap query you may user FedoraDS (389 Directory server): http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:AccessControl

You can see also OpenDS (https://www.opends.org)